# Finding next occurring tag and its enclosed text with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse text between the tag `<blockquote>`.  When I type `soup.blockquote.get_text()`.

I get the result I want for the first occurring blockquote in the HTML file.  How do I find the next and sequential `<blockquote>` tag in the file?  Maybe I'm just tired and can't find it in the documentation.

Example HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>header
</head>
<blockquote>I can get this text
</blockquote>
<p>eiaoiefj</p>
<blockquote>trying to capture this next
</blockquote>
<p></p><strong>do not capture this</strong>
<blockquote>
capture this too but separately after "capture this next"
</blockquote>
</html>
```

the simple python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = open("example.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
print.(soup.blockquote.get_text())
# how to get the next blockquote???
```

Comment: Whats the <blockquote> that you refer to , is it a HTML <blockquote> == https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_blockquote_test. If yes than does a HTML <blockquote> warrant any kind of special treatment than say other HTML TAG's ? IMHO it doesnt so am leaving this comment to clarify that . The bs4 or any other kind of HTML parsing code that shall work for "other HTML Tags" shall work just fine for a HTML -  <blockquote> , thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`find_next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) (If it not a sibling, use [`find_next`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) instead)

```
>>> html = '''
... <html>
... <head>header
... </head>
... <blockquote>blah blah
... </blockquote>
... <p>eiaoiefj</p>
... <blockquote>capture this next
... </blockquote>
... <p></p><strong>don'tcapturethis</strong>
... <blockquote>
... capture this too but separately after "capture this next"
... </blockquote>
... </html>
... '''

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> quote1 = soup.blockquote
>>> quote1.text
u'blah blah\n'
>>> quote2 = quote1.find_next_siblings('blockquote')
>>> quote2.text
u'capture this next\n'
```