# Find third occurring `<p>` tag using with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

As the title suggests, I'm trying to understand how to find the third occurring `<p>` of a website (as an example, I used the following website: http://www.musicmeter.nl/album/31759).

Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823229/finding-next-occuring-tag-and-its-enclosed-text-with-beautiful-soup), I tried the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get("http://www.musicmeter.nl/album/31759").text    # get HTML from http://www.musicmeter.nl/album/31759
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')                              # Get data out of HTML

first_paragraph = soup.find('p')    # or just soup.p

print "first paragraph:", first_paragraph

second_paragraph = first_paragraph.find_next_siblings('p')

print "second paragraph:", second_paragraph

third_paragraph = second_paragraph.find_next_siblings('p')

print "third paragraph:", third_paragraph
```

But this code results in the following error for the third_paragraph:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page_109.py", line 21, in <module>
    third_paragraph = second_paragraph.find_next_siblings('p')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_next_siblings'
```

I tried to lookup the error, but I couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using *siblings* i.e plural so you are getting a *ResultSet/list* back which you cannot call *.find_next_siblings* on.

If you wanted each next paragraph you would use **sibling** not **siblings**:

```
second_paragraph = first_paragraph.find_next_sibling('p')

print "second paragraph:", second_paragraph

third_paragraph = second_paragraph.find_next_sibling('p')
```

Which can be chained:

```
third_paragraph = soup.find("p").find_next_sibling('p').find_next_sibling("p")
```

A much simpler way is to use *nth-of-type*:

```
print(soup.select_one("p:nth-of-type(3)"))
```

You should also be aware that finding the third occurring *p* is not the same as finding the 2nd sibling to the first *p* you find on the page, using *nth-of-type* actually does find  the third *p* tag in the page, if the first *p* does not have two sibling *p* tags then your logic will fail.

To really get the third occurring p using find logic just use *find_next*:

```
  third_paragraph = soup.find("p").find_next('p').find_next("p")
```

Of if you want the first three use find_all with a limit set to 3:

```
 soup.find_all("p", limit=3)
```

Of using your original logic to get the first two:

```
first_paragraph = soup.find('p')    # or just soup.p



second, third = first_paragraph.find_next_siblings("p", limit=2)
```

If you only want `x` tags then only parse x tags, just be sure you understand the difference between finding the *third occurring `<p>` tag* and the 2nd sibling to the first p tag as they may be different.

Comment: Thanks, the `  third_paragraph = soup.find("p").find_next('p').find_next("p")` is the one the truly worked for me.

Comment: No worries, there is a subtle different between finding the third p anywhere on the page and finding certain siblings.

Comment: Yeah, that was I guess my main mistake. I have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

`.find_next_siblings('p')` returns a BeautifulSoup result set which is like a list in python. Try the following code instead.

```
first_paragraph = soup.find('p')
siblings = first_paragraph.find_next_siblings('p')
print "second paragraph:", siblings[0]
print "third paragraph:", siblings[1]
```