# Trying to find all of the text between multiple span tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a block of text from an article (http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK), below is the specific section of code that I want to get

```
<span id="midArticle_start"></span>

<span id="midArticle_0"></span>
<span class="focusParagraph"><p><span class="articleLocation">YANGON</span>
  Standing among the party seeing off Myanmar's new president as he left for Russia on Wednesday was leading businessman Htun Myint Naing, better known as Steven Law.</p></span>
<span id="midArticle_1"></span><p>Only the day before, the United States had added six of his companies to the Treasury's blacklist, a move that is unlikely to hamper the tycoon's business empire significantly.</p>
<span id="midArticle_2"></span><p>President Barack Obama's sanctions policy on Myanmar, updated on Tuesday, aims to strike a balance between targeting individuals without undermining development or deterring U.S. businesses eying the country as it opens up to global trade.</p>
<span id="midArticle_3"></span><p>Underlining how tricky that balance is, Law may actually gain commercially from the latest changes, even if they do make it harder for him to portray himself as an internationally accepted businessman close to the new democratic government.</p>
<span id="midArticle_4"></span><p>"Though (sanctions) are not meant to have a blanket effect on the country, their intended targets often play outsize roles ... controlling critical infrastructure impacting trade and business for ordinary citizens," said Nyantha Maw Lin, managing director at consultancy Vriens & Partners in Yangon.</p>
<span id="midArticle_5"></span><p>On Tuesday, Washington eased some restrictions on Myanmar but also strengthened measures against Law by adding six firms connected to him and his conglomerate, Asia World, to the Treasury blacklist.</p>
<span id="midArticle_6"></span><p>Yet the blacklisting, which attracted considerable attention in Myanmar, looks like a formality given that the companies were already covered by sanctions, because they were owned 50 percent or more by Law or Asia World. Law was sanctioned in 2008 for alleged ties to Myanmar's military.</p>
<span id="midArticle_7"></span><p>More important for Law was the U.S. decision to further ease restrictions on trading through his shipping port and airports, extending a temporary six month allowance set in December to an indefinite one.</p>
<span id="midArticle_8"></span><p></p>
<span id="midArticle_9"></span><p>PORTS BACK IN FAVOR</p>
<span id="midArticle_10"></span><p>Law is one of the most powerful and well-connected businessmen in Myanmar with close ties to China.</p>
<span id="midArticle_11"></span><p>He is not, however, universally popular at home or abroad because of alleged ties to the military, which ruled Myanmar with an iron fist until 2011.</p>
<span id="midArticle_12"></span>
```

The end goal is to have each sentence as separate objects that I can later use, such as

```
print(sentence1)
```

~Standing among the party seeing off Myanmar's new president as he left for Russia on Wednesday was leading businessman Htun Myint Naing, better known as Steven Law.

```
print(sentence2)
```

~  Only the day before, the United States had added six of his companies to the Treasury's blacklist, a move that is unlikely to hamper the tycoon's business empire significantly.

My code retrieves only the first sentence but nothing past that as shown below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
z = requests.get("http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK/")
url2 = 'http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK'
response2 = requests.get(url2)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, "html.parser")
first_sentence = soup2.p.get_text()
print(first_sentence)
second_sentence = soup2.p.find_all_next()
print(second_sentence)
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to get all of the sentences individually, it would be much appreciated. I've already tried methods discussed in other stackoverflow questions
[Finding next occuring tag and its enclosed text with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823229/finding-next-occuring-tag-and-its-enclosed-text-with-beautiful-soup) and [Using beautifulsoup to extract text between line breaks (e.g. <br /> tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275359/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-between-line-breaks-e-g-br-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that the [find_all_next()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method returns all matches that appear after the starting element (the previously matched `<p>`), and as you haven't specified what tag to match, it matches everything.

If you change that to `soup2.p.find_all_next("p")` you'll get all remaining `<p>` tags on the page, you can then iterate through them (or explicitly assign them if you like) by using something like

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, "html.parser")
first_sentence = soup2.p.get_text()
print(first_sentence)
for sentence in soup2.p.find_all_next("p")
    print(sentence.get_text())
```

Which is even simpler if you just remove the additional variables and use [findAll()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) instead:

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, "html.parser")
for sentence in soup2.find_all("p")
    print(sentence.get_text())
```

Comment: How would I go about iterating through the block of text that print(sentence.get_text()) returns. Is it possible to assign a value to each individual sentence?

Comment: It's probably easiest to put them into a dictionary or list for later handling, if the individual sentences don't need names you can just put them in a list using `sentences = list(map((lambda x: x.get_text()), soup2.find_all("p")))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just return all `<p>` elements within `<span>` where `id` equals 'articleText' using CSS selector `#articleText p` :

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url2 = 'http://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-usa-sanctions-idUSKCN0Y92RK'
>>> response2 = requests.get(url2)
>>> soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, "html.parser")
>>> for sentence in soup2.select("#articleText p"):
...     print(sentence.get_text())
...     print()
... 
YANGON Standing among the party seeing off Myanmar's new president as he left for Russia on Wednesday was leading businessman Htun Myint Naing, better known as Steven Law.

Only the day before, the United States had added six of his companies to the Treasury's blacklist, a move that is unlikely to hamper the tycoon's business empire significantly.

President Barack Obama's sanctions policy on Myanmar, updated on Tuesday, aims to strike a balance between targeting individuals without undermining development or deterring U.S. businesses eying the country as it opens up to global trade.

Underlining how tricky that balance is, Law may actually gain commercially from the latest changes, even if they do make it harder for him to portray himself as an internationally accepted businessman close to the new democratic government.

......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try : soup2.p.find_all_next(text=True)

like this:

```
second_sentence = soup2.p.find_all_next(text=True)

for item in second_sentence:

       print(item.split('\n'))
```